# Interesting properties of the function $(a,b)\mapsto a/(a-b)$

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

Consider the extremely simple function
$$f(a,b)=\frac a{a-b}.$$
This gives the coordinate where the line through $(0,a)$ and $(1,b)$ meets the $x$-axis.

I noticed that the function $f$ has some interesting properties:
$$\begin{gather}
f(a,b)+f(b,a)=1, \\
f(a,x)f(a,y) = f(a,x)f(x,y) + f(a,y)f(y,x), \\
f(a,x)f(b,x) = f(a,b)f(b,x) + f(b,a)f(a,x),
\end{gather}$$
These identities can be verified by calculation, but for the latter two it is hard to see *a priori* that they *should* be true.

By the way, if you imagine $f(a,b)$ as a directed edge from $a$ to $b$ in a graph, the three identities have an elegant graphical representation:
$$\begin{gather}
{}\rightarrow{} + {}\leftarrow{} = 1 \\[1em]
{}\nwarrow\nearrow{} = {}\overrightarrow{\nwarrow\ \ }{} + {}\overleftarrow{\ \ \nearrow} \\[1em]
{}\searrow\swarrow{} = {}\overrightarrow{\ \ \swarrow}{} + {}\overleftarrow{\searrow\ \ } \\[1em]
\end{gather}$$

I have a couple of questions:

1. Does $f$ fall into any well-studied class of functions? It's not even commutative or associative, but those properties above are interesting.
2. Is there an elegant way to prove these identities without laborious calculation, or to discover them (and any others I might have missed) starting only from the definition of $f$?

Comment: Why abstract-algebra?

Comment: I found that with a draw it is quick to see the properties you mencioned. 
Using this: *This gives the coordinate where the line through $(0,a)$ and $(1,b)$ meets the $x$-axis.*

Comment: I put in abstract-algebra because I'm wondering if $f$ forms a known algebraic structure. How did you get the second and third identities with a diagram? I'm very interested.

Comment: I'm on it, just the first propertie, there are a Maya trick to multiply using lines and I though it will helpfull but i noticed that no. working working on it, is interesant, also: $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x,y)=1 \wedge \lim_{y\to\pm\infty }f(x,y)=0 $$

Comment: Does $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ have similar properties?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: It satisfies $g(a,b)+g(b,a)=0$, but I haven't found anything interesting corresponding to the other two properties. Maybe they're there but I just don't know how to find them -- after all, the second property of $f$ I stumbled on by luck, and then I had to do a bunch of blind calculations to obtain the third.

Comment: possibly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree

Answer (score 2):

$f(a,b)$ is the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) $(a,\infty;0,b)$.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks! I know nothing about the cross ratio -- how well does it explain the three properties of $f$ I mentioned in the question?